# Optapy having problems with constraints (groupBy and sum)

Tags: group-by, sum, constraints, optapy

Just starting to test optapy, I have an error trying to use optapy, groupBy and sum:

> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable"

probably for the argument of sum. Any help?

```
def lecturer_teaching_load(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    print("Restricting by Teaching Load")
    return constraint_factory.forEach(SubjectClass) \
        .groupBy(lambda subject: subject.lecturer, sum(lambda subject: subject.teaching_load)) \
        .filter(lambda lecturer, load: lecturer.real_cap > load) \
        .penalize("Capacity conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
```

Idea is to penalize if the subjects planned for the same lecturer are too many.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I know Chris has been improving some of these CS cases that pass a function. Which version of optapy is this?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is you are using the python built-in `sum` function (which takes an iterable, and return a number), not the `ConstraintCollectors.sum` function (which takes a function, and return a ConstraintCollector).

JPype currently cannot distinguish between functional overloads without explicit casts, so currently you need to cast the lambda inside the sum to the proper type (in this case, `java.util.function.ToIntFunction`). This is done automatically for `Joiners`, but not for `ConstraintCollectors` (which use a variety of different types in different places, making it harder to automate the process without duplicating the API). This code should work:

```
from optapy.constraint import ConstraintCollectors
from java.util.function import ToIntFunction

def lecturer_teaching_load(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    print("Restricting by Teaching Load")
    return constraint_factory.forEach(SubjectClass) \
        .groupBy(lambda subject: subject.lecturer, ConstraintCollectors.sum(ToIntFunction @ (lambda subject: subject.teaching_load))) \
        .filter(lambda lecturer, load: lecturer.real_cap > load) \
        .penalize("Capacity conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
```